# Java Applet : inetAddress.getHostName() throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, applet, japplet

I am trying to get the hostname. `inetAddress.getHostName()` works in Java Applications, but in the applet, it throws `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

How can I get Host-Name in an applet?

Comment: What host name are you trying to get?

Comment: The local machine's host name.

Comment: That would probably be a security restriction. Look here http://lists.xcf.berkeley.edu/lists/advanced-java/2000-October/033028.html

Comment: I'm looking for an applet-specific workaround that'll give me the local machine name.

Comment: "applet-specific workaround"  It is not a 'work around', but the the only way to make the method work in an applet is to digitally sign the applet and convince the end user to trust it when prompted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()
```

and

```
java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()
```

work in applets, **only** when the applet is signed. To sign, one can use jarsigner utility, which is included with the JDK.

```
keytool -genkey -alias signFiles -keystore <gen_file> -keypass <key>-dname "cn=<somename>" -storepass <password>

jarsigner -keystore <gen_file> -storepass <password> -keypass <key> -signedjar <signed>.jar <unsigned>.jar signFiles
```

All values within `<...>` must be replaced by appropriate values.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you pass params to an applet. But I imagine you can use the javascript `window.location.hostname` variable to pass this value in to the applet.

Comment: @anirudh4444:  Note that questions can be down-voted as well.